# Jquery Form Submit, Async Call then Submit Form On Success

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the lat long of an address inserted into the form before the form is submitted.

Here is my code:

```
 var success = false;
var getLat = 0;
var getLng = 0;

function getLngLat() {
    var address = $(".save-new-address").val();
    if(!address) return false;
    if(success) return false;

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            console.log(results);
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            success = true;
            var newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                map: map  
            });
            $(".save-new-lat").val(results[0].geometry.location.lat);
            $(".save-new-lng").val(results[0].geometry.location.lng);
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        };                                        
    });
}


$("form#save-new-restaurant").submit(function () {
    getLngLat();
    if(success) { 
        return true;
    } else {
        getLngLat();
        $("form#save-new-restaurant").submit();
        return false;   
    }
});
```

Most of it is just copied from the google developers page.  However what I am finding is either the form is submitting too quick, and the details are being retrieved after the above function has finished,

I am just trying to get the data from google *when* the form is submitted, and when *i've got* the data I want to then submit the form.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead

```
var success = false;
var getLat = 0;
var getLng = 0;

function getLngLat() {
    var address = $(".save-new-address").val();
    if(!address) return false;
    if(success) return false;

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            console.log(results);
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            success = true;
            var newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                map: map  
            });
            $(".save-new-lat").val(results[0].geometry.location.lat);
            $(".save-new-lng").val(results[0].geometry.location.lng);

            $("form#save-new-restaurant").unbind("submit"); // unbinding event so getLngLat doesn't execute again
            document.getElementById('save-new-restaurant').submit();
            $("form#save-new-restaurant").bind("submit", formSubmitCallBack); // attaching event for further uses if require
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        };                                        
    });
}


$("form#save-new-restaurant").bind("submit", formSubmitCallBack);

function formSubmitCallBack() {
    getLngLat();
    return false;
}
```

Hope this will help !!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a deferred object.

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/

```
$("form#save-new-restaurant").submit(function () {
    var lngLat = getLngLat();
    $.when(lngLat)
        .done(function() {
            return true;
        })
        .fail(function() {
             //handle failure
         });
 }
```

Then in your other code

```
function getLngLat() {
    //stuff
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
           //do stuff
           deferred.resolve();
        } else {
            deferred.reject();
        }
    }
    return deferred;
 }
```

Comment: I like this idea, but I can't get it to work? It's submitting the form with blank lng/lats.